# JSF not reporting any errors: blank page returned with no errors logged

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, glassfish

For many issues, I am receiving very little feedback from JSF/Glassfish. For example, I have a JSF page which contains:

```
<p:tabView rendered="#{cc.attrs.model.ready}" value="#{cc.attrs.model.allFeatures}" var="feature">
    <p:tab title="#{feature}">
        <h:panelGroup id="#{feature}">
            <h:outputText value="test"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Navigating to the page returns a HTTP 200 result, but the page is completely empty (seen by using Firefox's inspector). There is no evidence of an error in the Glassfish logs. If I remove `id="#{feature}"`, the webpage loads fine.

**My question is:** why is there no evidence of an error occurring? With many of my issues I am just getting a blank response and no errors or stack traces.

**Extra details:**

The page's URL is:

```
localhost:8080/myWebApp/Search.xhtml
```

My `web.xml` contains:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
    <!-- Set to production as primefaces gives annoying warnings on development -->
</context-param>
```

and

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I am using JSF 2.2 with Glassfish 3.1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a custom exception handler, ensure that it logs all errors while developing, otherwise you may be 'handling' an error by doing nothing.

A JSF2.x custom exception handler is defined in faces-config.xml by:

```
<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>
        nz.co.tradeintel.util.CustomExceptionHandlerFactory
    </exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```